# My transition doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx

In this code, when invoking the `play()` method for the transition `(PathTransition pt;)` the program hides the orange rectangles and displays no transitions. It has no syntax error. I'm trying to get the rectangle to circle around the circles.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Test__javafx extends Application{
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane p = new Pane();
        Button b = new Button("Play");
        b.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 3em;" + 
                "-fx-background-color: #66a3ff;" +
                "-fx-min-width: 120;" +
                "-fx-min-height: 40;" +
                "-fx-max-width: 120;" +
                "-fx-min-height: 40;" +
                "-fx-cursor: hand;" + 
                "-fx-text-fill: white;");
        b.setLayoutX(320);
        b.setLayoutY(400);


        b.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {

            Circle big = new Circle();
       // create rectangle for big circle
       Rectangle bigRec = new Rectangle();
            Circle circ = new Circle();
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            //event for small rectangle
            r.setWidth(20);
            r.setHeight(30);
            r.setLayoutX(362);
            r.setLayoutY(335);

            r.setArcWidth(5);
            r.setArcHeight(5);
            r.setStyle("-fx-fill: #ff9933;" +
                    "-fix-stroke-width: 20;" +
                    "-fix-stroke: #ff4d4d;");

            //event for small circle
            circ.setStyle("-fx-fill: #88ff4d;" +
                    "-fx-stroke-width: 12;" +
                    "-fx-stroke: #3399ff;");
            circ.setCenterX(370);
            circ.setCenterY(400);
            circ.setRadius(50);

            // event for big circle's rectangle
             bigRec.setLayoutX(205);
            bigRec.setLayoutY(375);
            bigRec.setWidth(30);
            bigRec.setHeight(20);
            bigRec.setArcWidth(5);
            bigRec.setArcHeight(5);
            bigRec.setStyle("-fx-fill: #ff9933;" +
                    "-fix-stroke-width: 20;" +
                    "-fix-stroke: #ff4d4d;");

            // big circle
            big.setStyle("-fx-fill: #88ff4d;" +
                    "-fx-stroke-width: 12;" +
                    "-fx-stroke: #3399ff;");
            big.setCenterX(370);
            big.setCenterY(400);
            big.setRadius(150);
            p.getChildren().addAll(big, bigRec, circ, r);
            // transition for small circle and rectangle

            PathTransition pt = new PathTransition();
            pt.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
            pt.setPath(bigRec);
            pt.setNode(bigRec);
            pt.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
            pt.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            pt.setAutoReverse(false);
           // if you comment the play method it shows the rectangle
             // but not any transitions obviously
           pt.play();

             PathTransition pt2 = new PathTransition();
            pt2.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
            pt2.setPath(circ);
            pt2.setNode(r);
            pt2.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
            pt2.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            pt2.setAutoReverse(false);
             // if you comment the play method it shows the rectangle
             // but not any transitions obviously
           pt2.play();

        });
        p.getChildren().add(b);
        p.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #88ff4d;");
        Scene s = new Scene(p, 750, 650);
        stage.setScene(s);
        stage.show(); 
    }
    // launch Application
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first `PathTransition`, you have set both the path and the node as bigRec. Set the path as big instead of bigRec.

```
PathTransition pt = new PathTransition();
pt.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
pt.setPath(big); // Make this change
pt.setNode(bigRec);
pt.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
pt.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
pt.setAutoReverse(false);
```

Also your transition is happening but at the coordinates you set for your rectangles. In order to see the rectangles on the circle, remove the layout values from the rectangle. I.e remove the below code

```
//Code to be removed
bigRec.setLayoutX(205);
bigRec.setLayoutY(375);

r.setLayoutX(362);
r.setLayoutY(335);
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed such an error. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ibrahim Java If this is answering your question mark it to help future users.